# How to find last but one array element in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How to fetch the last but one array element

```
 $ele1 = array(23,24,45,56,32,78)
```

to get maximum value `max($ele1)`

The expected return output is 56

Comment: 56 is not last but one array element in your list.

Comment: I think he wants to remove the last so that 56 will become the maximum value

Comment: $ele1[count($ele1)-2] gives you last but one element

Comment: order the list based on value? and so it gets last but one so that he gets 56?

Comment: I will not be knowing position of the last but one element  56

Comment: 56 is the last but two. Do you actually mean that you want to get the second biggest value of the array?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the last element from your array, use

```
array_pop($ele1)
```

It will remove the last value, then you will have `max($ele1) = 56`

Answer (score 1):

Sort your array using `arsort($ele1)`; and then get last but one element using `$ele1[count($ele1)-2]`